# PHP Compare DateTimes with Timezone

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, timezone

I have to use UTC as the default for my entire project.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

However, in one instance, I need to be able to compare a DateTime against the current time in London. But it seems that TimeStamps and DateTime comparisons can only compare the UTC value of any DateTime due to the default setting. For instance:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$t = clone $d;
$t->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

var_dump($t);
{"date":"2017-06-02 15:41:34.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"}

var_dump($d);
{"date":"2017-06-02 14:41:34.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}
```

The hours show a 1 hour difference which is correct. But:

```
var_dump($d == $t);
true
var_dump($d->getTimeStamp() == $t->getTimeStamp());
true
```

I want to show the the London time ($t) as greater than UTC time ($d).

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps are always in UTC so you'll always get the same value no matter what timezone the object currently is in.

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved it myself. Take the example in the original post and do

```
time() + $t->getOffset();
```

which is current time + the Timezone offset of the London DateTime (which is currently 3600).